# How to display an sql command on a datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm working on a WPF page where I choose a target database and I can write a SQL command on a text field that when executed, will render a table with the results.

So far, I have the code which allows me to choose the database and send the SQL command and return a `DataReader`, [here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o74Qj.png).

My problem is that I have to return the command result in order to display it on my data grid and I am not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: Have a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: Can you post some code? Are you using CodeBehind, MVVM, a custom user control? Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @hendryanw as i said i have sqlcommand and i have to display the result  on my dataGrid view.

Comment: Have you read up on using SQL and datagrids?

Comment: @BugFinder i did but until now i didnt figure out how to do it

Comment: read more :P but one word of caution.. whats stopping me from doing "drop <stuff>" as my sql command, or create user ... and grant.. and give myself rights, or change everyone elses passwords?